# Google UrlFetch Service with CouchDB OAuth

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, couchdb

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlfetch), Google Apps can "Fetch resources and communicate with other hosts over the Internet". I would like to access my couchdb instances using OAuth. CouchDB [supports](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Authentication) OAuth. What I am planning to do is this:

1. Enable the OAuth authentication handler in the CouchDB config: `{couch_httpd_oauth, oauth_authentication_handler}`
2. Define a *database reader* for the databases that I want to make available.
3. Test the setup with a scripting tool.
4. Setup the Google App application to use the CouchDB OAuth authorizing user.

Does somebody here have comments on this particular setup?
Can somebody provide a simple test script (preferably python) to access an OAuth 1.0 endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CouchDB OAuth example in python you could use [script from wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Link_Collection_Authentication_and_Authorization#couch_httpd_oauth%3a%3aoauth_authentication_handler) about OAuth authorization.

However, since it written in one-liner style, here is flow version:

```
import oauth
import httplib

URL='http://localhost:5984/_session'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'example.com'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'sekr1t'
TOKEN='user1'
SECRET='tokensekr1t'

consumer = oauth.OAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
token = oauth.OAuthToken(TOKEN, SECRET)
req = oauth.OAuthRequest.from_consumer_and_token(
    consumer, token=token, http_method='GET', http_url=URL, parameters={}
)
req.sign_request(oauth.OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), consumer,token)

con = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost', 5984)
con.request('GET', URL,headers=req.to_header())
print con.getresponse().read()
```